# Calling RSS feed using For statement results in non-object error

Tags: php, rss, for-loop

I am displaying an RSS feed using a simple For statement...

for ($i=0; $i<=19; $i++)

Now this works without a problem and displays 20 entries using echo, but my problem is that if the feed accessed has less than 20 items I get a non-object error.

Basically, when the for loop has to quit early it gives me a non-object error.

Can anyone recommend how to get around this?

EDIT:

Some more info that was requested:

It's just a list of links formated in an RSS feed. Several actually, some will have more than 20 items some less, but I want them all displayed using the same code.

Basically...

```
for ($i=0; $i<=19; $i++)
  {
  $item_title=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('title')
  ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

 echo ($item_title);

}
```

Comment: Can you provide a little more of your code? What kind of object are you loading your RSS feed into? You can probably check if the object exists using `empty()` or use a foreach loop instead of a for loop.

Comment: It's just a list of links formated in an RSS feed. Several actually, some will have more than 20 items some less, but I want them all displayed using the same code.

Basically...

    for ($i=0; $i<=19; $i++)
      {
      $item_title=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('title')
      ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
    
     echo ($item_title);
    
    }

Answer (score 0):

Its always safe to find number of elements. Then use

for ($i=0; $i< $length; $i++)

Comment: The problem is I only want to display a maximum of 20. How would I use $length but limit to 20? Im not even sure how to find the number of elements in a RSS feed?

Comment: if($length > 20) {
 $length = 20;
}

This will save length as minimum of $length and 20

Comment: `$length = min($length, 20);`

Comment: Cant get it to work, both of these give me nothing:
`if($length > 20) { $length = 20; }
for ($i=0; $i<$length; $i++)`

and
`$length = min($length, 20);
for ($i=0; $i<$length; $i++)`

And the following one only gives me ONE result:
`$length = min($length, 20);
for ($i=0; $i<=$length; $i++)`

Soooo close anyone got any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Check the length of `$item` before you do your `for` statement:

```
if(count($item) > 19) {
    //do your for statement
} else {
    //do a foreach statement
}
```

Or, you may be able to check if `$item[$i]` exists (isn't `null`) before trying to parse it out. I'm guessing that's where your error is stemming from.

```
for ($i=0; $i<=19; $i++) {
    if(array-key-exists($i, $item)) {
        //do everything you want
    }
    $i++;
}
```

This second method will cycle through 20 times, no matter what, however. When the inner `if` is false, it'll still cycle until `$i` is 20. So if you only have 10 entries in your RSS, the `for` will run an extra 10 times (20 total). I would suggest checking the length before the `for` and then using a `foreach` if the length is less than 20.

Here is an example using the `if` statement method.

```
// set $length to the lenght of your RSS array
$length = count($your_rss_array);

// if your RSS array has more than 20 items, limit $length to 20
if(count($item) > 20) {
    $length = 20;
}

// $length will either be as long as the RSS array is, or will be 20
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $item_title = $x -> item($i) -> getElementsByTagName('title') -> item(0) ->
                  childNodes -> item(0) -> nodeValue;
    echo $item_title;
}
```

Comment: @user979564 I don't see why not. Can you post your full code (or a working portion of your code) that shows the above methods not working?

Comment: $length = min($length, 20);
    for ($i=0; $i<=$length; $i++)
      {
      $item_title=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('title') 
      ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
    
      echo ($item_title);
    
       }

Comment: @user979564 I added a code example above, to my posted answer.